# What would the possible compression be with Pi

Tags: statistics, recreational-mathematics, pi

Imagine a data file with data (a movie, an image, etc.). A file is just a sequence of 1 and 0. Since Pi contains infinite many binary digits, that image should be found in Pi somewhere and instead of sending someone a file, we could just send them the offset to that file in Pi.

The problem with this approach (ignoring the implementation details) is that the offset could be larger than the file itself, meaning that the offset can be longer than the file itself.

However for some files (or parts of file) it's possible to instead send the index in Pi instead of the file data itself.

What is the biggest space save that can be reached by using index in Pi instead of the data itself for saving a arbitrary file?

Comment: $(1)$ It is unknown whether $\pi$ (in binary expansion) contains every finite digit string $(2)$ If this is the case, we could in principle just give the position of the starting bit and its length to determine the complite file. But since the vast majority of all files is random and hence not compressible significantly, this number will usually be huge and to write it down would not require less effort.

Comment: Of course, tons of useless files can be easily compressed with $\pi$ this way.

Comment: I agree with @Peter.  Writing the index out is (in most interesting cases) longer than the original message.

Comment: @Peter you're probably right, but how do I prove that? What's the proof for the index being bigger than the file itself, and how often will this happen?

Comment: @iveqy We cannot prove that there is no useful file we can compress this way since we do not know the digits from , say , position $10^{10^{100}}$ on. Maybe, they compress the bible or Romeo and Julia from Shakespeare. What we can prove is that the VAST majority of the files cannot be compressed significantly. This is a well known result. Study the Kolmogorov-complexity for more details.

Comment: There are $2^n$ possible bit strings of $n$ bits.  You roughly expect the first instance of a given one to start around position $2^{n-1}$ in $\pi$, which has about the same number of bits as the file.

Comment: We don’t know that $\pi$ has this property. Having an infinite number of digits doesn’t ensure that every finite sequence is in those digits.

Comment: Another problem with your approach is that you still have to calculate the digits of Pi even if you know the correct offset. That can take an arbitrarily large amount of time. More so you do not tend to save space by taking a finite length algorithm and storing it an infinite length one. It's unclear how doing reverse compression like this would save space.

Comment: @CyclotomicField A very good point ! Even if we get a fantastically compressed file this way, the decompression can be infeasible in pratice. We actually have this situation in Chaitin's constant. Even if we knew the first $n$ binary digits, this would not help us in practice to actually solve the halting problem upto programs of length $n$.

Comment: Taking the question literally, as being about "a random file", the answer is that you can save at most a constant amount of space, because that's the definition of "random". If, on the other hand, "random" was meant to informally mean "arbitrary", then exponential compression is easy for some files. The file consisting of the first $n$ bits of $\pi$ can be specified by saying "the first $n$ bits of $\pi$", which has length roughly $\log n$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField thats an already solved problem https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula

Comment: @iveqy If you mean the formula for the $n$-th bit of $\pi$, this is a method allowing to calculate digits without calculating all the other digits. This does not mean that we can calculate the $10^{100}$ th digit immediately. This would still require much time.

Comment: @peter could you explain that? I dont follow you